# Postfix warning: dns_get_fixed

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, spf

I have a recently setup Postfix/Dovecot simple mail server (if there is such a thing).

It was stable, and worked without issue for about 2-3 weeks, until I wanted to get SPF setup. Now, it still mostly works, but seeing a strange error--which may or may not be related.

In my log, I am seeing:
postfix/smtp["some number"]: warning: dns_get_fixed: bad class: 4096

Additional to that warning, that:
postfix/smtp["same number as above"]: warning: no MX host for t-online.de has a valid address record

lastly,
 (Name service error for name=mx03.t-online.de type=A: Malformed or unexpected name server reply)

I have searched around using keywords from the above information, but have drawn nothing but blanks. I feel like I am on an island.

Can anyone throw me a bone?

I have tried using dig to verify the "t-online.de" and the "mx t-online.de" records, and they seem legit. t-online is the major german telecom, so as much as I would like to think the error is on their end, I can't believe that for very long.

Where should i start to solve this problem? Is it a dns problem on my end?

EDIT: forgot to mention a not so minor detail. Mail is not being sent/received to the above domain name, t-online.de.

Comment: Looks like a problem with your local DNS resolver. Check `/etc/resolv.conf` to find out where that might be.

Comment: tried: cat /etc/resolv.conf.     search mydomain.com    nameserver fe80::1%enp4s0   I know the later, the nameserver is my router. the %enp4s0, not sure what that is? Will read up on resolv.conf for now.

Comment: What machine is at fe80::1 then?

Comment: my dsl router, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Now you know what to look at.

Comment: Thanks for being there =) Will go through my due diligence starting from the interface, and work my way up. I think it has to do with my dns resolution to the outside world, somehow. will report back or ask questions as they arise. The fe80::1 is probably the server itself. I just noticed that all interfaces on my network start with that. I think it's some IPv6 naming? not sure.

Comment: Yes, fe80::1 is almost always the self-assigned link-local address for a local home/SOHO router. It is indeed an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Cleaning up my /etc/resolv.conf file solved my problem. I ensured to add my IP to it, and for good measure, added the standard google dns (8.8.8.8).

With proper deliver, I was able to get a "proper response" that my IP was being blacklisted by them. Hopefully get the cleared up shortly.

Comment: All cleared up now. I just had to email them, to clear the ip blacklist. Apparently t-online.de, or the primary german telekom, will often block entire ranges of suspect subdomains, and unblock them when asked.